# Filtering with grep and regex

Tags: regex, grep

I need to filter strings starting with "abc".
Example: I have a text file a.txt, which contains:

```
youtube
showme adx
girlyouaremyfriend abcde
abcxe
```

after filterint it with grep, this is the result I would like to obtain:

```
abcde  
abcxe
```

Thanks

Comment: You should at least provide what you tried. I'm sure `man grep` is worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep -o "\babc\w*" a.txt` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your help ,but it didnt do the job ,its result is :
abc
abc

Comment: It works for me, so I don't know. You copied it correctly ? the \w* part is important.

Comment: ya ,that's my wrong .thanks much !

Comment: This fails with line like this `more text ifabcde has more` it should not print `abcde` since its not start of string as requested.

Comment: You're right, edited for correctness since it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if I am interpreting your question correctly, then you should try this (in Linux command line):

```
cat a.txt | tr " ", "\n" | grep "^abc"
```

Explanation:

- cat reads the file and sends to stdout
- tr splits the space separated strings into newlines
- grep does the matching and returns the strings as indicated

If you are dead-set keen to get the output in one line, you can append:

```
| tr "\n", " "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -e "^abc" -e " abc" a.txt|sed 's/.*\(abc[^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: a little bit long ,but it is good .thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  `awk` version:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^abc/) print $i}' file
abcde
abcxe
```